# Visual Studio 2017 ругается на множества в Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

[image: О чём говорит сама среда.]

Когда я пытаюсь инициализировать множество, visual studio сообщает о том, что необходим Python 2.7 или ниже. Но для чего? Я не совсем понимаю. Так на моей машинке стоит Python 3.8 и среда его прекрасно видит, даже может спокойно скомпилировать код. Но по прежнему ругается на инициализацию. В чём дело?

Comment: Судя по надписи `bytes` MSVS думает, что вы пытаетесь объявить байты... У меня на линуксе все хорошо инициализировалось, и, как я понял, у вас тоже все хорошо. Тогда это можно списать на качество IDE, которая, впрочем, всегда чудит

Comment: Может у вас модуль проверки синтаксиса от старого питона стоит?

Comment: Нет, о таком модуле я слышу впервые( Вы могли бы рассказать подробнее?

Comment: Скорее всего в настройках проекта у вас стоит версия Python ниже 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, Visual Studio 2017 просто не поддерживает python 3.8. Visual Studio 2019 умеет с ним работать.